Catch Array Data Index Changing in v-for
App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const data = ref([{
  id: "1",
  data: "aa"
},
{
  id: "2",
  data: "bb"
},
{
  id: "3",
  data: "cc"
},
{
  id: "4",
  data: "dd"
},
])

function add() {
  data.value.splice(2, 0, {
    id: "5",
    data: "ff"
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="add">add</button>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
      <Comp :index="index" :data="item"></Comp>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Comp.vue
<script setup>
import { watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  index: {
    default: 0,
    required: true
  },
  data: {
    default: {
      id: "",
      data: ""
    },
    required: true
  },
})

watch(() => props.index, (value) => {
  console.log(value)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ props.data.id }}
  </div>
</template>

I have one parent component and one child component. I use v-for to reproduce Comp.vue. I want to add new value between in data array. And I want to see in watch that index changing. When I code like this, there is no any changing in index. How can I get changed index?

data.value = data.value.splice... probably work

@ErdemÜn if I code like that, it gonna render all of component. I dont want that. Because array length can be 65535.

<div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="item.id">
  <Comp :index="index" :data="item"></Comp>
</div>

if I describe like this :key="item.id", vue understands that is unique and catch array changing for index. When I code like this, solved problem.
